# Why table cell width not changing with CSS?

Tags: c#, css, web-parts

This question may look weird, but it is happening to me. I am using one `<asp:Table>`  in my visual webpart. In code behind I am generating few rows and attaching those rows to table. Table is displaying perfectly. But the problem is that, if try to change the particular cell/column width via CSS it is not allowing me to change. I am trying to change with Developer tools for temporary purpose, but it does not seem to work. See the below screen shot.

[image]

Even if i change the layout of table cell it is not changing to new value. It is displayed as fixed one. I tried giving width of a cell in code behind like  `myCell_01.Width = new Unit(250);` , but this is also not working. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a few issues when using table. Table has a strict structure, but anyway, it can be changed via css property 'table-layout:fixed'
Table example:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/2zrue/>?
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know how to change the normal html table via css, but this table is rendering from the C# code. It is not taking the values what I am giving.

Comment: Are you able to provide a code in pastebin on somewhere, to take a look?